# acces+VB - cmdClose() when data is saved/not saved

Tags: vb.net, save

I made a database to register employees.

In the from Change Employee I have a save and a close button. When data is filled in and the save button is pressed the data is stored in the correct table.

The close button events I find on the internet all prompt a messagebox with the question if the user wants to save the data or not. I would like that my event only asks that if the data is not already saved. Asking for save when it's not needed is quite annoying.

So if the user presses the save button, the close button doesn't have to ask if the user wants to save the data and it just closes the form. 
If the user forgot to press save button and presses the close button I would like that the close button shows a messagebox that asks if the user wants to save the data.

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: It's a pretty irritating thing to do, I'm not sure if there is an easy way but as far as I can tell, there isn't. One way you could go about it is to create a class level Boolean variable, which is set to to `True` on form load. Then, each time a control value is changed (Eg, `TextBox.TextChanged`), the Boolean is set to `False`. Then, on the save button, set it to `True`. On form close, check if the value is `True` or `False`, and only show a `MessageBox` if it's `False`.

Comment: Hello David, thank for your answer.

To be honest, I have no idea how to try this out.

I thought I type Textbox.TextChanged but I don't get that event option. Only .Text, .TextAlign and .TextFormat.

Can you tell me how to set this up?

Comment: Just double click the `TextBox` and the method will be created. You need to do some research on `vb.net` and the Visual Studio IDE before you being programming.